# Passing user name and password dynamically to Curl POST command

Tags: json, unix, curl

trying to pass user name and password dynamically to Curl POST command, but it is throwing errors as unable to Validate user name and password

The command is working fine if the username and password is hardcoded.

Static Command:

```sh
curl -i -X POST https://somewebsite.com/service/nonuilogin \
-H 'Accept:application/json' \
-H 'content-type:application/json' \
-H 'host:somewebsite.com' \
-d '{"ping_uname":"serviceaccount","ping_pwd":"acc@123"}'
```

Dynamic command:

```sh
curl -i -X POST https://somewebsite.com/service/nonuilogin \
-H 'Accept:application/json' \
-H 'content-type:application/json' \
-H 'host:somewebsite.com' \
-d '{"ping_uname":"$user_name","ping_pwd":"$password"}'
```

[image]

```json
{
  "error": "Unable to log in user. Validate that the username/password are valid",
  "translationKey": "FD_AUTH_USER_UNABLE_TO_VALIDATE"
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Please [edit] your question and explain where you expect `$user_name` and `$password` to come from. Are these shell variables in a script that contains the `curl` line? In this case I suggest to show example assignments to these variables. Yout string `'{"ping_uname":"$user_name","ping_pwd":"$password"}'` is in single quotes. The shell doesn't expand variables inside single quotes. You have to use double quotes and escape the double quotes that are part of the actual text.

Comment: yes, the user_name and password are shell variables.

Comment: Please don't use comments to provide requested information, **[edit] your question** instead. And, please, don't post images of text. Copy&paste the output or error message to your question *as text* and format it as a code block, e.g. by using the `{}` tool of the editor field.